# problema de lógica para eliminar elementos repetidos en un array con elementos int aleatorios en c

Tags: array, c, lógica

Buen día tengo una consulta en c
Estoy haciendo un programa que genere un arreglo dinámico con números aleatorios, los datos almacenados deben ser de tipo entero, "Esto ya lo e realizado", luego toca generar otro arreglo a partir del original sin números repetidos en el siguiente código plantee la lógica que creería que iría, pero no me da alguien me podría ayudar a mirar en que estoy errando, por favor !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void * malloc(size_t size);

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  int * original, * array, * nuevo, n, j, i, cont =0, cont2 = 0;
  srand(time(NULL));
  printf("El tamaño del arreglo generado aleatoriamente es de: ");
  n = rand() % 20;
  original = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
  nuevo = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
  printf(" %d elementos\n", n);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    *(original + i) = rand() % 10;
    printf("\n %d : %d", i, *(original + i));
    //*(arrays+i) = *(original+i);
  }
  
  * (nuevo) = * (original);
  
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)  {
    if ( * (original+i+1)!= *(nuevo+j)) *(nuevo+i+1) = * (original+i+1);  
    else if(* (original+i+1)!= *(nuevo+j))break;            
    }
  }
  
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("\n %d : %d", i, *(nuevo + i));
    //*(arrays+i) = *(original+i);
  }

    printf("\nContador : %d \n %d",cont,cont2);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El algoritmo sería en pseudocódigo algo así:

```
Para cada elemento del array original:
   Si el elemento no está en el array nuevo:
      Añadirlo
```

La clave entonces es determinar si el elemento está o no en el array nuevo. Comprobar esto obliga a iterar sobre todos los elementos del array nuevo, mirando si alguno de ellos es igual al elemento en cuestión. Pero cuando digo todos los elementos no me refiero a `n`, sino al número de elementos que tenga en ese momento (ya que el array `nuevo` comienza vacío y va creciendo a medida que se le añadan elementos hasta un máximo de `n`).

Así pues necesitamos una variable que diga cuántos elementos hay en `nuevo`. Ésta puede ser por ejemplo `cont` que comienza valiendo 0 y que incrementaremos cada vez que añadimos uno más. Y también puede ser útil escribir una función que nos diga si un elemento dado está o no en un array. Tal función podría ser la siguiente:

```
int dato_en_array(int dato, int *array, int len_array) {
  for (int i=0; i<len_array; i++) {
    if (dato == array[i]) return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Haciendo uso de esta función, el algoritmo que va rellenando el array `nuevo` queda muy sencillo:

```
  cont = 0;  // Tamaño inicial del array nuevo
  for (i=0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (!dato_en_array(original[i], nuevo, cont)) 
       nuevo[cont++] = original[i];
  }
```

Al salir de este bucle `cont` nos dice cuántos elementos tiene el array `nuevo`, por lo que podemos mostrar esa información así:

```
printf("\nHay %d elementos diferentes\n", cont);
for (i = 0; i < cont; i++) {
    printf(" %d : %d\n", i, *(nuevo + i));
}
```

Ejemplo de ejecución:

```
El tamaño del arreglo generado aleatoriamente es de:  10 elementos

 0 : 8
 1 : 7
 2 : 8
 3 : 2
 4 : 6
 5 : 2
 6 : 0
 7 : 8
 8 : 6
 9 : 2
Hay 5 elementos diferentes
 0 : 8
 1 : 7
 2 : 2
 3 : 6
 4 : 0
```